# Displaying an image in Jade

Tags: pug

So I have the following Jade code `h3(class="text-muted") MedKit` that displays the word "MedKit" at the top of a web page and right next to it I want to display an image. How would I go about doing this and how should I upload/save the image I want to display?

Comment: Could you frame your question about one specific problem and post the code that you have attempted to solve it ?

Comment: My specific problem is I don't know how to display an image in Jade

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can display a image by using the img tag. In jade the syntax looks like:

```
img.className#IdName(src="/path-to-image.jpg" alt="Image Title")
```

To display it next to your h3 tag:

```
.image-block
  h3 Hello
  img.className#IdName(src="/path-to-image.jpg" alt="Image Title")
```

I suggest you read about [piping in jade too](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/). Just ensure that you replace the spaces with tabs else it will give a compilation error.

Answer (score 5):

Pug code to display image from db is...

```
img.image(src='/' + img_path_var )
```

old jade code

```
img.image(src='/#{img_path_var}')
```